# issue running thunderbird-91 with firejail thunderbird profile

Tags: apt, email, thunderbird

I have been using thunderbird-78 installed through apt package repository. I was able to run thunderbird in firejail mode using the command `firejail --profile=/etc/firejail/thunderbird.profile thunderbird %u`.
However I wanted to use thunderbird 91 so I uninstalled apt package and downloaded thunderbird91.tar.gz package file from thunderbird website as per instructions in this post `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367236/update-thunderbird-78-to-91-on-ubuntu-20-04` . I extracted all the files in `/home/ajayc/snap/thunderbird`  folder.

Now I am not able to run thunderbird using the command `firejail --profile=/etc/firejail/thunderbird.profile /home/ajayc/snap/thunderbird/thunderbird` . The error I get when running the command in terminal is as give here.

```
ajayc@ubuntu2004:~$ firejail --profile=/etc/firejail/thunderbird.profile /home/ajayc/snap/thunderbird/thunderbird
Reading profile /etc/firejail/thunderbird.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-passwdmgr.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-xdg.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-usr-share-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox-common.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-exec.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-interpreters.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-var-common.inc
Warning: networking feature is disabled in Firejail configuration file
Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Parent pid 31210, child pid 31211
Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Warning: not remounting /run/user/1000/doc
Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Child process initialized in 117.76 ms
Error: no suitable /home/ajayc/snap/thunderbird/thunderbird executable found

Parent is shutting down, bye...
```

However, `firejail --noprofile /home/ajayc/snap/thunderbird/thunderbird`  works.
Please suggest what is issue here which needs to be resolved. My system specs are given below.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 21.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.80.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-37-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 7.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by following the approach suggested in the following post.

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622505/how-to-run-external-executables-within-firejail
```