Upgrade to 24.04.1 - thunderbird does not import my old emails
My upgrade from 20.04.06 to 24.04.1 was a disaster - the installer hung and I was forced to interrupt it which corrupted my 20.04 kernel.  I was forced to do a fresh install of 24.04.1 and then try to put all my files back manually afterwards (I have backups of my precious files on other disks).
Once I had my shiny new 24.04 running I installed the snap version of Thunderbird from the App Center and then set about putting my previous thunderbird emails back (dating back to the 1990s) - but although it starts up and successfully pulls new emails down from my ISP's IMAP server, it does not find my old folder structure at all.  This means I can see new emails, but nothing older than a couple of days.  Like I said, I have thousands of mails I want to access from over the years.
I tried two ways:

importing my old mail directory via the Import tool

pointing the profiles.ini at my old mail directory


Both fail to find my folders.
This is worrying as I have always been able to get thunderbird to see my mail directories before during previous bumpy upgrades over the years.
I am aware that thunderbird on 20.04 was installed via apt and via snap on 24.04 and have worked out where the profile directories are on both.
I note that if I try to view my Settings > Server Settings I see this instead:
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: chrome://messenger/content/am-server.xhtml
Line Number 171, Column 21:
<menuitem
--------------------^
I could really use some help please.
Thanks,
Chris

On a search found server settings show XML Parsing Error: undefined entity Location which has the same error message, and a link to a solution. I haven't seen the error myself, so unable to confirm the solution works.

The following link describes how to copy your .thunderbird profile from 'APT' to 'SNAP' location and vice versa. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526123/how-do-i-migrate-my-email-on-thunderbird-to-a-new-computer/1526175#1526175 and the following to revert the 'SNAP' back to an 'APT' installation. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1528030/thunderbird-will-not-create-profile-in-chosen-folder-on-a-different-partition/1528043#1528043

Thanks Chester - with troubleshooting mode I have managed to repair my Server Settings!   I still need to figure out how to get it to see my mail folders.

Please edit your OP to elaborate on how you installed TBird on the new 24.04.1 system. After installing, did you open TBird before doing configs and/or reinjection of old TB data folders ? If not, what configs did you do to point TB to the old emails folder ? TB is the trickiest thing to get going on Ubuntu after a fresh install. But worse than that, if you delay too long in sorting it out you might encounter version compatibility issues, i.e. newer versions of TB might not accept old email data created by an older TB version.

I have the same error on the server settings for all my email addresses. Nonetheless my emails are working fine, in and out.
So I think this is a TB-wide error rather than something wrong with your own setup. Refer to TB forum reports on this.
There is a proposed fix here and it is to be consolidated into the 128.3.2 version.

I am assuming that you are using the snap version of TB. apt uses a version of TB that is several versions older than the currently issued one.
So the profiles folder should be in
/home/your-username/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird/
and be named something like rxcjkbf1.default or some such long alphanumeric string followed by .default  . . .
So you'll have to replace any installation-created xxxxxxx.default folder with the one extracted from your old TB data, e.g. yyyyyyyy.default .
Then you go to the profiles.ini config file alongside the yyyyyyyyyyy.default folder in /home/your-username/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird/  and edit it so that
Path=yyyyyyyyy.default

then save and exit.
It might be safer to reboot the system before reopening TBird to check if it's "seeing" your folder structure and old emails.
Here's hopin' . . .
It's possible that the emails from the apt TB on 20.04 may be incompatible with the newer TB version on snap.
In that case, I would be inclined to - temporarily, at least - uninstall the snap version of TB and then install the apt version - which is likely the one you were using on your 20.04 system. Try the routine described above with respect to injecting the old email data. If successful then update the TB version to the newest available from apt.

Thanks for the in-depth and considered response. Unfortunately it just refuses to see my folders when I try this method.  I have tried several times with tweaks but nothing works. I will keep trying but if no luck I will move to the apt version.  If I do this, am I just kicking the can further down the road?  Presumably at some point in the future the apt version will change and stop seeing my folders?

Have you tried uninstalling TB & purging all the associated files and then do a fresh install ? Keep TB offline until the configging of the profile is done. Then restart your system and open TB. From past experience I would advise sorting this out a.s.a.p. So if you need help, go get it from a local Ubuntu/Linux consultant. Go on your local Linux user group in your state for names of local Linux proficient people. Every day that passes increases the likelihood of new versions of TB coming out and you don't want to get into a version lockout.

@Chris Bamford  Please scan through this post of 2020 when I moved over to Linux and had your problem. It provides a link on old TB versions that you can install manually so that your profile is compatible with that version on your system.

Thanks Trunk, I will try this. (What do you mean by "It provides a link on old TB versions that you can install manually"?)

OK, so it is now working!
I tried Trunk's suggestion of a fresh snap install followed by going offline while performing the config shuffle (copying in the old profile folder and updating profiles.ini) and this time it worked when I started TB.  Once I went back online all my original folders were visible and healthy.  There's obviously something crucial that happens during the first run.
The Account settings were broken as they were trying to find a file in my old file tree, but clearing the cache and restarting TB solved this.
Thanks for all suggestions so far.

@Chris Bamford I mean this link here for old Thunderbird versions. Glad it worked out.
