# Updating Thunderbird 78 to 91 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, icons, thunderbird

I propably took a wrong way to update Thunderbird.
I found in *Ubuntu Software* the TB icon for the new 91.4.0 version (December 29th 2021) and clicked the *Install* button.

When restarting email, it still opened the old 78.14.0 (from my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS). Clicking *Applications* icon I can find two identical Thunderbird icons. I understand there is somewhere a kind of starting points for two different versions of TB, but of course it is important to change the default. Should I manipulate those or do something differently from beginning?

I could not find a direct answer from [How to update Thunderbird 78 to 91 on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367236/how-to-update-thunderbird-78-to-91-on-ubuntu-20-04/1384300#1384300) or anyway I need more detailed instructions.
I am not very used to apt but noticed by `apt show -a thunderbird` there are two TB packages but propably neither is the newest:

```
Package: thunderbird
Version: 1:78.14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Priority: optional
Section: mail
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Mozilla Team <ubuntu-mozillateam@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 210 MB
Provides: mail-reader
Depends: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.30), libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0), libcairo2 (>= 1.10.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6), libfreetype6 (>= 2.10.1), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.4), libharfbuzz0b (>= 0.6.0), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libstdc++6 (>= 9), libx11-6, libx11-xcb1 (>= 2:1.6.9), libxcb-shm0, libxcb1, libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.4.5), libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6, libxrender1, libxt6
Recommends: myspell-en-us | hunspell-dictionary | myspell-dictionary, libcanberra0, libdbusmenu-glib4, libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
Suggests: thunderbird-gnome-support, ttf-lyx, libotr5
Conflicts: mozilla-thunderbird
Breaks: enigmail (<< 2:2.2), jsunit (<< 0.2.2-2ubuntu1), thunderbird-gnome-support (<= 3.0.4+nobinonly-0ubuntu3), tinyjsd (<< 1.2+git1-1ubuntu1)
Replaces: mozilla-thunderbird, thunderbird-gnome-support (<= 3.0.4+nobinonly-0ubuntu3)
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, xubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop
Download-Size: 50,5 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: Sähköposti-, RSS- ja uutisryhmäsovellus roskapostisuodatuksella varustettuna
 Thunderbird is a full-featured email, RSS and newsgroup client that makes
 emailing safer, faster and easier than ever before. It supports different
 mail accounts (POP, IMAP, Gmail), has a simple mail account setup wizard,
 one- click address book, tabbed interface, an integrated learning spam
 filter, advanced search and indexing capabilities, and offers easy
 organization of mails with tagging and virtual folders. It also features
 unrivalled extensibility.

Package: thunderbird
Version: 1:68.7.0+build1-0ubuntu2
Priority: optional
Section: mail
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Mozilla Team <ubuntu-mozillateam@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 178 MB
Provides: mail-reader
Depends: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.30), libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0), libcairo2 (>= 1.10.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6), libfreetype6 (>= 2.10.1), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.3), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.4), libharfbuzz0b (>= 0.6.0), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.14.0), libstartup-notification0 (>= 0.8), libstdc++6 (>= 9), libx11-6, libx11-xcb1 (>= 2:1.6.9), libxcb-shm0, libxcb1, libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6, libxrender1, libxt6
Recommends: myspell-en-us | hunspell-dictionary | myspell-dictionary, libcanberra0, libdbusmenu-glib4, libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
Suggests: thunderbird-gnome-support, ttf-lyx
Conflicts: mozilla-thunderbird
Breaks: thunderbird-couchdb, thunderbird-gnome-support (<= 3.0.4+nobinonly-0ubuntu3)
Replaces: mozilla-thunderbird, thunderbird-gnome-support (<= 3.0.4+nobinonly-0ubuntu3)
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, ubuntu-desktop-default-languages, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, xubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop
Download-Size: 42,6 MB
APT-Sources: http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
Description: Sähköposti-, RSS- ja uutisryhmäsovellus roskapostisuodatuksella varustettuna
 Thunderbird is a full-featured email, RSS and newsgroup client that makes
 emailing safer, faster and easier than ever before. It supports different
 mail accounts (POP, IMAP, Gmail), has a simple mail account setup wizard,
 one- click address book, tabbed interface, an integrated learning spam
 filter, advanced search and indexing capabilities, and offers easy
 organization of mails with tagging and virtual folders. It also features
 unrivalled extensibility.
```

What is the basic difference between the installations of new and old versions? Are they both apt packages? How should I eliminate the old one?

Comment: It looks like you have installed the `snap` version of Thunderbird 91. The snap versions of all the apps (including Thunderbird) works differently than the deb versions. To check, use the command `snap list thunderbird`, If you want to remove the snap version, use `sudo snap remove thunderbird`. This will remove the new snap version and keep the original version.

Comment: Thanks @user68186 . But when using the method 1 recommended in referenced thread (`apt remove thunderbird`, ` snap remove thunderbird`, `snap install thunderbird`) I propably lost all my local email archives :( How could I find them again?

Comment: **Important**: Before updating TB, you should backup your profile following advices from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data

Comment: Well, not so bad. My old TB profile stayed in `~/.thunderbird` and the new profile was created in `~/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird` . Orders to restore data to a new profile can be found in https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data . No backup was needed in my case

Answer (score 3):

The newer version you installed is a Snap package. The old version is coming from the regular Ubuntu software sources.

You can remove any of these using the Snap store. You will find two versions there. The one coming from Snap.io is the Snap version. Remove the other version.

The Thunderbird profile of your current version is stored under `~/.thunderbird`. The profile of the snap version, however, is stored in a `.thunderbird` folder under `~/snap/thunderbird/common`.

To have your current profile settings adopted by the snap version so your email accounts and settings are preserved, first make sure none of the Thunderbird versions is running. Then delete (or rename) the directory `~/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird` and move the `~/.thunderbird` directory to `~/snap/thunderbird/common/`.

In recent versions, newly installed versions will not automatically adopt a current default profile, but create a new one. To have it use your old profile, run thunderbird from the commandline with the -P flag (`thunderbird -P`): this opens thunderbird with the profile manager, where you will be able to select your correct profile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved! The old version was an *apt* package and the new is a *snap* package, as @vanadium said. The old profile was safe in `~/.thunderbird` and and can be restored to `~/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird`.

To do:

1. Ensure the old version is *apt* by `apt list -a thunderbird` command
2. Remove the old by `sudo apt remove thunderbird`
3. Create the new snap version by `sudo snap install thunderbird`
4. Restore profile following carefully orders at *support.mozilla.org* [Profiles - Where Thunderbird stores your messages and other user data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data).

Comment: Sorry, we were writing simultaneously. I think my answer was a bit more detailed